# Netsuite Rest OAuth using PHP

Tags: php, curl, oauth, netsuite

I am attempting to connect to Netsuite from PHP via Rest (not a Restlet) using OAuth 1.0 and I am receiving a 401 Invalid login when attempting to connect with the Netsuite audit saying invalid signature. I have scoured the web for examples and can't see what the issue is with my code in comparison. Postman is working fine with the same credentials.

```
$timestamp = time();
$nonce = mb_substr(md5(mt_rand()),0 , 11);
$baseString = "POST&" . rawurlencode(NSQL_URL) . "&" .
    rawurlencode(
            "oauth_consumer_key=" . rawurlencode(CONSUMER_KEY) .
            "&oauth_nonce=" . rawurlencode($nonce) .
            "&oauth_signature_method=" . rawurlencode('HMAC-SHA256') .
            "&oauth_timestamp=" . rawurlencode($timestamp) .
            "&oauth_token=" . rawurlencode(TOKEN_ID) .
            "&oauth_version=1.0
            &realm =" . rawurlencode(ACCOUNT_ID)
            );

$sig_string = urlencode(CONSUMER_SECRET) . "&" . urlencode(TOKEN_SECRET);
$signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha256", $baseString, $sig_string, true));
$url = NSQL_URL;
$auth_header = "OAuth "
    . 'oauth_signature="' . rawurlencode($signature) . '", '
    . 'oauth_version="1.0", '
    . 'oauth_nonce="' . rawurlencode($nonce) . '", '
    . 'oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA256", '
    . 'oauth_consumer_key="' . rawurlencode(CONSUMER_KEY) . '", '
    . 'oauth_token="' . rawurlencode(TOKEN_ID) . '", '
    . 'oauth_timestamp="' . rawurlencode($timestamp) . '", '
    . 'realm="' . rawurlencode(ACCOUNT_ID) . '"';

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://xxxxxx.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/query/v1/suiteql',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
    "q": "SELECT c.email AS email, c.companyName AS company, t.tranId AS document, t.tranDate AS date FROM customer c, transaction t WHERE t.entity = c.id AND t.type = \'SalesOrd\'"
}',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'prefer: transient',
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Authorization: ' . $auth_header
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: Can you link to the documentation that you are basing this signature calculation on? There is a lot of URL encoding going on there, I wonder if that is not perhaps a bit too much at some point or other ...

Comment: @CBroe https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_1534941088.html Is the docs

Comment: `$sig_string = urlencode(CONSUMER_SECRET) . "&" . urlencode(TOKEN_SECRET);` - not sure if it makes a difference, but they are explicitly using `rawurlencode` for that part over there.

Comment: Doesn't seem too sadly.

Comment: You are introducing additional whitespace into your $baseString, because you have not concatenated individual strings between `"&oauth_version=1.0` and `&realm =" . rawurlencode(ACCOUNT_ID)` like you did with all the values before, but you have _one_ literal that goes over two lines there - so you are putting an additional newline and whitespace between those two parameters. And you got an additional space between `realm` and `=` there.

Comment: Plus, the "REST Web Services Base String Example" from the docs does not even have `&realm=...` at the end, it ends with `oauth_version%3D1.0`

Comment: Looks like the concatenation issue was the problem, I had tried a few different versions both with and without realm due to other answers on stack. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Xand94, I am interested in your final answer, can you post here please!